# HTML5 Canvas image flashes and script does not wait for image to be downloaded

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am using Firefox 19.0.2 on Ubuntu Linux.
I'm learning HTML5 but find that the following code's image
flashes repeatedly. Furthermore, I would like for the image
to finish downloading before the script stars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta encoding="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello Canvas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = drawCanvas;
      function canvasSupportEnabled() {
        return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
      }
      var Debugger = function() { };
      Debugger.log = function(message) {
        try {
          console.log(message);
        } catch (exception) {
          return;
        }
      }
      var x = 0;
      var y = 0;
      function drawCanvas() {
        if (!canvasSupportEnabled())
          return;
        var theCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
       context.fillStyle = "#ffffaa";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 300);
        context.fillStyle = "#000000";
        context.font = "20px Sans-Serif";
        context.textBaseLine = "top";
        context.fillText("Hello World!", 195, 80);
        context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        context.strokeRect(x, y, 490, 290);
        var platypus = new Image();
        platypus.onload = function() {
          context.drawImage(platypus, x, y);
        }
        platypus.src = "http://www.wildwatch.com.au/uploads/Platypus/PLATYPUSweb1.jpg"
        window.setTimeout(drawCanvas, 200);
        x = x + 5;
        y = y + 5;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Canvas.</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300">Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas.</c
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I solve these two problems. Do I need to double-buffer and how can I do it?
How do I detect an onload event for the images to finish being downloaded?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will load the image first then create and draw the canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta encoding="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello Canvas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = drawCanvas;
        function canvasSupportEnabled() {
            return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
        }
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;

        function drawCanvas() {
            if (!canvasSupportEnabled())
                return;
            var platypus = new Image();
            platypus.onload = function () {
                var theCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
                context.fillStyle = "#ffffaa";
                context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 300);
                context.fillStyle = "#000000";
                context.font = "20px Sans-Serif";
                context.textBaseLine = "top";
                context.fillText("Hello World!", 195, 80);
                context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
                context.strokeRect(x, y, 490, 290);
                context.drawImage(this, x, y);
            }
            platypus.src = "http://www.wildwatch.com.au/uploads/Platypus/PLATYPUSweb1.jpg"
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Canvas.</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300">Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas.</canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Minnesota! I have fond memories of living in "friendly" Fridley Minnesota. @Jason Posit: you might move the drawing code to a separate function that is called in Michael's platypus.onload.  That will make your animation easier to create. And Jason, google "requestAnimationFrame".  It's the best new toy for animation!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is the `setTimeout` call. The first run of the `drawCanvas` function causes the image to start loading. Once the image is loaded, it'll draw on the canvas, but the subsequent `drawCanvas` calls caused by the timeout will cause the whole canvas to get filled with the rect you're drawing and thus making the image disappear.

The `onload` callback will not fire again due to the image already having been loaded.

The simplest way to fix it would be to use a preloader for the images. Basically instead of using your current `window.onload` handler, use another function which loads your images and stores them in some variables. Once it has finished loading the images, have it call `drawCanvas` which you would modify to use one of the stored images instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following did it for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta encoding="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello Canvas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = drawCanvas;
        function canvasSupportEnabled() {
            return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
        }
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;

        function drawCanvas() {
            if (!canvasSupportEnabled())
                return;
            var platypus = new Image();
            platypus.onload = function () {
                var theCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
                context.fillStyle = "#ffffaa";
                context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 300);
                context.fillStyle = "#000000";
                context.font = "20px Sans-Serif";
                context.textBaseLine = "top";
                context.fillText("Hello World!", 195, 80);
                context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
                context.strokeRect(x, y, 490, 290);
                context.drawImage(this, x, y);
            }
            x = x + 5;
            y = y + 5;
            setTimeout(drawCanvas, 200);
            platypus.src = "http://www.wildwatch.com.au/uploads/Platypus/PLATYPUSweb1.jpg"
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Canvas.</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300">Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas.</
  </body>
</html>
```